# Exception: [.LookupUtil] Error looking up property. How to display hibernate result as table on jsp page using display tag?

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, jsp-tags, displaytag

I am trying to display a result obtained from Hibernate query call as a table on JSP using display tag (http://displaytag.sf.net) but it's not working.
The query contains a count function to get the row count.

```
public List<MyClass> getResults(String section) 
{
    try
    {
        List<MyClass> resultList = null;
        final Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

            //Forming the inner query.
            DetachedCriteria innerCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(MySecondClass.class,"mySecondClass")
                    .add(Restrictions.eq("mySecondClass.section", section))
                    .setProjection(Property.forName("classId"));

            //Form the outer query now.
            final ProjectionList projection = Projections.projectionList();
            projection.add(Projections.rowCount(),"count");
            projection.add(Projections.groupProperty("companyName"));

            final Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(MyClass.class, "myClass");
            criteria.add(Subqueries.propertyIn("classId", innerCriteria));
            criteria.setProjection(projection);

            resultList = criteria.list(); 
            logger.info("Returned result with list "+resultList.size());
        return resultList;
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The query below is represented using above hibernate code:

```
Select Count(*),companyName from MyClass
where classId in (Select classId from MySecondClass where section='someValue')
group by companyName
```

The query returns correct value both in query browser as well as through hibernate in java. When trying to display the result in JSP using:

```
<display:table id="rowId" pagesize="5"
                        requestURI="/admin/getResult" name="resultList"
                        style="width: 100%;"
                        class="displayTable table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed">

                        <display:column property="companyName" title="Company"
                            class="displayTable"></display:column>
                        <display:column property="count" title="Row Count"
                            class="displayTable"></display:column>
                    </display:table>
```

While running the application from UI, the following error is shown:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Exception: [.LookupUtil] Error looking up property "companyName" in object type "[Ljava.lang.Object;". Cause: Unknown property 'companyName'
>   org.displaytag.util.LookupUtil.getBeanProperty(LookupUtil.java:141)
>       org.displaytag.model.Column.getValue(Column.java:124)
>       org.displaytag.model.Column.createChoppedAndLinkedValue(Column.java:201)

The binding of result set to the display table tag is not being correctly done.
I've tried understanding other information in StackOverFlow but nothing seems to be wrong with the code.
Also how do I display the count value in Java side.

Comment: Somehow it is not able to get the property name out of list object. How do I provide getter for count which is a dynamic property set in projection?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try to :

1) Create a class with 2 fields  which represents your data 
ex :

```
    class Result
    {
      Long count;
      String companyName;

      // Getter & Setter
    }
```

2/ In this class add a constructor beside the default one

```
public Result(Long count, String companyName)
{
 this.count = count;
 this.companyName = companyName;
}
```

3/ In your criteria function add a transformer as follow :

```
    projection
   .add(Projections.groupProperty("companyName"))
   .setResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanConstructorResultTransformer(Result.class.getConstructors()[1]));
```

hope that helps

Comment: Creating a class for 2 variables and then passing its object to UI will decrease the performance, I guess as the resultset would have thousands of entries (may be more). I was trying to convert the value somehow to String or any suited format so that the mapping could be done. Thanks for the suggestion.